# Is there a python module in linux similar to win32gui for sending input to inactive windows

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Basically title, is there anything like this? I googled around a bit but couldn't find anything relevant to Linux only... win32gui postcommand is what I'm looking for an equivalent on Linux

Comment: You can try this : https://pypi.org/project/python-libxdo/

Comment: That looks promising, I can't check it right now (at work) does it allow hard-coding which window to send to? I saw it had a 'select_by_click' method

Comment: It should allow hard-coding window id like xdotool does.

Comment: Awesome, post as an answer and I'll try when I get home and mark yours as correct if it does work

Answer (score 0):

The module python-libxdo should be able to achieve what you wanted to do.

In particular, you can hardcode window id.